# display listing of R source files in knitr

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sweave, include sourced R-Function files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715916/sweave-include-sourced-r-function-files)

I am using knitr to make a report. I wrote all the analysis code as functions in a separate R file. I then wrote the analysis commands in an R Markdown file using those functions. The final generated HTML file looks nice. I wanted to add a last section in the R Markdown document where I could list all the functions from the original R file. I did the following:

````
Source code for functions used
========================================================

```{r}
source('my_functions.r');
```
````

The output of this is as follows in the generated HTML file :

```
## 
## > xx <- function(a = 100) {
## +   plot(1 : 100);
## + }
```

This does not look pretty. I want to get the listing of the R file in knitr properly formatted. I can always copy and paste, but am looking for a more elegant solution. Thanks!

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/10726383/559676